# how to delete a sub directory whose name is appended to the end of its parent folder's name

Tags: bash, find, cut, xargs

Parent folder contains subdir name appended at the end

Delimiter is underscore `_`:

```
a_b_c  (parent folder contains sub directory name at the end)
  |c/ (to be deleted)
  |..
d_f
  |..
  |f/ (to be deleted)
g_h
  |h/ (to be deleted)
  |..
```

Output should be

```
a_b_c  (parent folder contains sub directory name at the end)
  |..
d_f
  |..
g_h
  |..
```

What I have with me is get the subdirectory name

```
"$PWD" |rev|cut -d"_" -f1|rev  (input: a_b_c output: c)
```

Not sure how to delete the subdirectory.
Help please!

Comment: What's wrong with `rmdir */_*`?

Comment: @user1934428: It removes dirs with different suffixes, too.

Comment: I understood that it should remove all directories one level down, which start with an undescore. Then you have to describe how the directories to be deleted should look like, and which should be left alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the directories, use parameter expansion to remove everything before the last underscore:

```
#! /bin/bash
for dir in * ; do
    last=${dir##*_}
    [[ -d $dir/$last ]] && rmdir "$dir/$last"
done
```

Comment: Hi @choroba where to place this script? I am not sure how to give the directory input

Comment: Place it wherever you like, call it from the root of the hierarchy. Or, send the root directory as a parameter and start the script with `cd "$1" || exit 1`.

Comment: I placed alongside or in same level to that of dir it needs to be processed. It didn't work

Comment: @DineshRavi: How did you run it? How did it fail?

Comment: I just copied into test.sh file & placed at same level of the dir a_b_c  & executed. It gave no error & flipside it did not delete the c sub folder

Comment: @DineshRavi: How exactly did you execute it?

Comment: bash test.sh thats it

Comment: What is an example of a real path you wanted to delete?

Comment: /home/dinesh/auto_car/car/ is the folder which needs to be deleted
/home/dinesh/food_fruits_apple/apple/  is the folder which needs to be deleted

even edge case 
/home/dinesh/school/school needs to be deleted

Comment: I see. I thought the subdirectory name is `_c`, not just `c`, but you probably used `_` as a drawing character :-(

Comment: Just remove the `_` after `last=`.

Comment: If you want it to operate also on directories without `_` in their name, use `for dir in *`.

Comment: If the directories aren't empty, use `rm -rf` isntead of `rmdir`.

Comment: But list them before you delete them so you don't lose any data.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' dir;
do 
  if test -d "$dir/${dir#*_*_}";
  then 
       echo "rm -Rf $dir/${dir#*_*_}";
       # rm -Rf "$dir/${dir#*_*_}";
  fi;
done <<< "$(find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*[[:alpha:]]{1}_[[:alpha:]]{1}_[[:alpha:]]{1}$" -print0)"
```

Utilising find to execute a regular expression search for directories only that have the pattern outlined, redirect the output back into a while loop, reading them into a variable dir. We then strip the last character with ${dir#****} before removing the directory path if it exists.

Echo the remove command before removing the comment marker to execute.

Comment: Utilize the `find` commands `-print0`option to [handle file names containing newlines](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) and to handle them in your while loop change `while read dir` to `while IFS= read -r -d '' dir`

Comment: Thanks for input @RobC I've amended the answer with the improvements.

Comment: @RamanSailopal How to pass the input root directory name to this script?

Comment: Replace the . in find for the path

Comment: Hi I copied above code into test2.sh & placed alongside a_b_c & executed using bash test2.sh. It didn't echo the command. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Run the find command manually first and make sure that it is listing the directories required.